# domain.com needs to be re routed to IP_ADDRESS:8080 nginx config weird configuration

Tags: nginx, dns, server

I have the following configuration in my nginx conf file for my domain

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name domain.com

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header  host http://domain.com;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
```

}

and when I got to domain.com -> nothing I have to append :8080 and Bam! I get the app just fine

however, I want to be able to just redirect domain.com -> to localhost:8080 where the app is running.

How can I fix this in my nginx config file under sites-available

Thank you,

Comment: Your `server_name` is missing a `;` and the `proxy_set_header Host` should not include the scheme. Try: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: I've done some rework after reading the following blog article - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name hippokros.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.241.191.56:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Comment: the node test script

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Node Server running');

Comment: is there an effin blog that takes you step by step on setting up 1 node app and having it setup via nginx you could provide me please

Answer (score 0):

have a /nginx/sites-available conf file as following afterward make a symbolic link to it at /nginx/sites-enabled/

```
 server {
listen 80;

server_name domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
}
```

inside javascript file

create the server with the private ip addr of the server NOT LOCAL HOST
like the following

```
//change ip address form localhost to the private IP address of server
app.listen(3000, '192.241.191.56', function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3001!');
});
```